# Send UDP broadcast message with wxWidgets

Tags: udp, wxwidgets

Using wxWidgets 2.8.9 on Mac/Win/Linux, how do I send a UDP broadcast message? Receiving is working using wxDatagramSocket, but it's not obvious to me how I would go about SENDING a UDP broadcast message.

Answer (score 2):

In principle simply using wxSOCKET_BROADCAST in the socket flags should work (it's going to result in SO_BROADCAST being set for the socket).